# How to pass In-memory Object to Watson Visual Recognition service using Python SDK

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson, object-storage, data-science-experience

I am using IBM data Science Experience notebooks to create a custom classifier for the visual recognition service. I have the training zip files loaded into Object storage. But when I try to create the custom classifier it fails with the error message

> "explanation": "Cannot execute learning task  : Could not train classifier. Verify there are at least 10 positive training images for at least 1 class and at least 10 other unique training images."

I am using Swiftclient to access the object storage and then converting the contents to BytesIO to pass it to create_classifier function

```
conn = swiftclient.Connection(
    key=credentials['password'],
    authurl=credentials['auth_url']+"/v3",
    auth_version='3',
    os_options={
        "project_id": credentials['project_id'],
        "user_id": credentials['user_id'],
        "region_name": credentials['region']})

Class1 = conn.get_object(credentials['container'],'imageset1.zip')
Class2 =  conn.get_object(credentials['container'], 'imageset2.zip')
Class3 = conn.get_object(credentials['container'], 'imageset3.zip')
```

Comment: how many positive training images are there in the container?

Comment: @RiyaMRoy I have 50 training images for each class.  3 zip files each containing 50 images.

Comment: Can you please provide the code ? Are the images still zipped on Object Storage ?